# Problem understanding transfer functions of second order filters

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, control, control-system, laplace-transform

The transfer function of any second order filter can be found by analyzing the circuit using the Laplace transform.

For example the transfer function of a second order low pass passive RLC filter is : 
\begin{equation}\frac{V_o}{V_i} = \frac{R}{s^2RLC+sL+R}
\end{equation}
For active filter there will be gain too.

But while doing simulation, I found the transfer functions are quite different. They are built using damping ratio and resonant frequency.

[image]

I can't understand how they have derived that transfer function. **Can anyone explain me how can I get the transfer function of any filter just by taking resonant frequency and damping ratio into consideration?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109076/discussion-on-question-by-jack-danniels-problem-understanding-transfer-functions).